# alternative for "(?"

Tags: regex, whitespace, regex-lookarounds

We have a regular expression containing `(?!\s)` but the regex engine used does not allow to use lookahead assertions. Complete regex is

```
^(?!\s)(.*)(\S)$
```

Can anyone please suggest any alternative ways of achieving same functionality with out using a lookahead.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Complete regex is as below. Please let me know if any other details needed. Thanks. 

pattern: ^(?!\s)(.*)(\S)$

Comment: Use `^\S(.*\S)?$` or `^\S(?:.*\S)?$`

Comment: Thanks. This one ^\S(?:.*\S)?$ still has "(?"

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^\S(.*\S)?$
```

It will match

- `^` - start of string
- `\S` - a non-whitespace char
- `(.*\S)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\S`  -  a non-whitespace char
- `$` - end of string.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s1Henk/1) using the Go regex engine (RE2) that does not allow lookaheads.